# Searching specific string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

## I have a string

```
import re
name = 'simranjeet kumar'

print (re.findall(r'^s.', name))

output: ['si']
```

But I am expecting ['simranjeet'],may I know why I am not getting simranjeet and why I am getting only ['si'] I mean string of length 2.

Comment: note, that `findall` is for matching all(multiple) occurrences of substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions `.` means any ONE symbol. To extract MANY any symbols use `+` or `*`. You are extracting a word until the space. I would solve this task like this:

```
re.findall(r'^(.+?)\s', name)
# or
re.findall(r'^(s.+?)\s', name)
# or
re.findall(r'^(\S+)', name)
# or
re.findall(r'^(s\S+)', name)
```

\s means any space symbol. \S means any non-space symbol. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for more information.